# Send emacs buffer to arbitrary Python process

Tags: python, emacs, read-eval-print-loop, swank

I like the `python-send-buffer` command, however I very often use Python embedded in applications, or launch Python via a custom package management system (to launch Python with certain dependencies).. In other words, I can't just run "python" and get a useful Python instance (something that `python-send-buffer` relies on)

What I would like to achieve is:

- in any Python interpreter (or application that allows you to evaluate Python code), import a `magic_emacs_python_server.py` module (appending to `sys.path` as necessary)
- In emacs, run `magic-emacs-python-send-buffer`

This would evaluate the buffer in the remote Python instance.

Seems like it should be pretty simple - the Python module listens on a socket, in a thread. It evaluates in the main thread, and returns the `repr()` of the result (or maybe captures the stdout/stderr, or maybe both). The emacs module would just send text to the socket, waits for a string in response, and displays it in a buffer.

Sounds so simple something like this must exist already... IPython has `ipy_vimserver`, but this is the wrong way around. There is also `swank`, while it seems very Lisp-specific, there is [a Javascript backend](https://github.com/ivan4th/swank-js) which looks very like what I want... but searching finds almost nothing, other than some vague (possibly true) claims that SLIME doesn't work nicely with non-Lisp languages

In short:

- Does a project exist to send code from an emacs buffer to an existing Python process?
- If not, how would you recommend I write such a thing (not being very familiar with elisp) - SWANK? IPython's server code? Simple TCP server from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[comint](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ComintMode) provides most of the infrastructure for stuff like this. There's a bunch of good examples, like [this](http://www.squidoo.com/emacs-comint) or [this](http://curiousprogrammer.wordpress.com/2009/03/27/emacs-comint/)

It allows you to run a command, provides things `comint-send-string` to easily implement `send-region` type commands.

[dbr/remoterepl on Github](https://github.com/dbr/remoterepl/tree/48076af9a4e79db40fcd6acc0b092bd00b492fe1) is a crude proof-of-concept of what I described in the question.

It lacks any kind of polish, but it mostly works - you import the `replify.py` module in the target interpreter, then evaluate the `emacs-remote-repl.el` after fixing the stupid hardcoded path to `client.py`

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't `shell-command` give you what you are looking for?  You could write a wrapper script or adjust the `#!` and `sys.path` appropriately.

Comment: So use `shell-command` to get the buffer contents into script? That sounds like a good starting point, thanks!